# Multiple Targets on prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I've configured prometheus on Centos, version details are follows.

```
prometheus-2.5.0.linux-386
```

I've added two targets on the prometheus.yml configuration file, all the servers node exporters are running. Config as follows,

```
    scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "node"
    scrape_interval: "15s"
    target_groups:
    - targets: ['192.168.x.x:9100','192.168.x.y:9100']
```

But in the prometheus UI Tragets only showing single node other is not showing. If I remove one node existing node is showing. How can I monitor multiple nodes. But in Grafana Dashboard shows **Multiple Series Error**.

Answer (score 15):

I've configured with this configurations on prometheus.yml

```
    # my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'node'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.x.x:9100']
    - targets: ['192.168.x.y:9100']
    - targets: ['192.168.x.z:9100']
```

Answer (score 12):

for later reference, following config works well on prometheus V2.3.1 version.

1. prometheus yml config:

```
- job_name: 'etcd-stats'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['10.18.210.2:2379','10.18.210.199:2379','10.18.210.16:2379']
```

.......

2. Web UI targets
   [image]

Answer (score 6):

You can scrape the multiple targets in prometheus. Try this way:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Scrape targets every 15 seconds
  scrape_timeout: 15s # Timeout after 15 seconds

  # Attach the label monitor=dev-monitor to all scraped time series scraped by this server
  labels:
    monitor: 'dev-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "job-name"
    scrape_interval: 10s # Override the default global interval for this job
    scrape_timeout: 10s # Override the default global timeout for this job
    static_configs:
    # First group of scrape targets
    - targets: ['localhost:9100', 'localhost:9101']
      labels:
        group: 'first-group'

    # Second group of scrape targets
    - targets: ['localhost:9200', 'localhost:9201']
      labels:
        group: 'second-group'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Newer versions of Prometheus use "static_configs" rather than "target_groups". The other answer has the most up to date version.